# Splitting up a Drupal database

Tags: 7, database

Is it possible to split the Drupal database into multiple databases. For example I have one database having the watchdog table and another database having all the other tables?

I know if I created my own tables I could store them in a separate database and use the following:

[How to connect to multiple Databases in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109261/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-drupal-7)

```
db_set_active('your_second_db_alias');
$query = db_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");
db_set_active();
```

Comment: Can you describe what task you're hoping to achieve this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For watchdog specifically, you could use [hook_watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7) to route the message where you need it, and don't use the dblog module ([dblog's hook_watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.module/function/dblog_watchdog/7)) if you don't want it logged to the default database.

For other (core or 3rd party) data, it depends on whether there is an appropriate hook to interrupt the intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better served using [Syslog](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog) for logging without cluttering your database.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question. It could be any tables that we would move out. (This is not my idea BTW but I have been tasked to look into it)